# best practice to deploy outlook add-in

Tags: node.js, office365, outlook-web-addins

I developed and On Send Add-in for outlook, it works fine when I host the service locally and add it as the custom add-in.

Now I need to deploy it on our organisation's office 365, and I have to host the service somewhere (written in nodejs).

my question is
1. is there an out of box solution from office 365 to host the add-in service?
2. if I have to host it on a server within our organisation, I guess I have to update the manifest.xml to use the new servers' IP instead of localhost. Will office 365 be able to access the IP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deploy it just as you would any other kind of web site, as that's what an Office add-in basically is.  There is no special Office 365 way of hosting a web site that happens to be an add-in.  But you would have to update any URLs in the manifest to point to your production site.  You still need to deploy the manifest itself to the end users, or to an admin who can install the add-in for all users in their Office 365 tenant.

Comment: I wrote my add-in using node.js. To deploy node.js project, it needs app.js. But the project i generated using https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office doesn't have app.js file. Do you know what is the best way to host it?

Comment: I think you're dealing with a configuration issue. You can use any kind of web site host that you want for an Office web add-in. I don't know node.js so you may want to rephrase your question for that framework